# Undefined reference error for template method

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, linker

This has been driving me mad for the past hour and a half. I know it's a small thing but cannot find what's wrong (the fact that it's a rainy Friday afternoon, of course, does not help).

I have defined the following class that will hold configuration parameters read from a file and will let me access them from my program:

```
class VAConfig {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& lhs, const VAConfig& rhs);

private:
    VAConfig();
    static std::string      configFilename;
    static VAConfig*        pConfigInstance;
    static TiXmlDocument*   pXmlDoc;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> valueHash;

public:
    static VAConfig* getInstance();
    static void setConfigFileName( std::string& filename ) { configFilename = filename; }
    virtual ~VAConfig();

    void readParameterSet( std::string parameterGroupName );
    template<typename T> T readParameter( const std::string parameterName );
    template<typename T> T convert( const std::string& value );
};
```

where the method `convert()` is defined in `VAConfig.cpp` as

```
template <typename T>
T VAConfig::convert( const std::string& value )
{
    T t;
    std::istringstream iss( value, std::istringstream::in );
    iss >> t;
    return t;
}
```

All quite simple. But when I test from my main program using

```
int y = parameters->convert<int>("5");
```

I get an `undefined reference to 'int VAConfig::convert<int>...'` compilation error. Ditto for `readParameter()`.

Looked at a lot of template tutorials but coul not figure this out. Any ideas?

Comment: An hour and a half isn't so bad...it killed me for 3 yesterday.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Templated code implementation should never be in a `.cpp` file: your compiler has to see them at the same time as it sees the code that calls them (unless you use [explicit instantiation](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1C75fSEw/) to generate the templated object code, but even then `.cpp` is the wrong file type to use).

What you need to do is move the implementation to either the header file, or to a file such as `VAConfig.t.hpp`, and then `#include "VAConfig.t.hpp"` whenever you use any templated member functions.

Comment: Thanks Seth and Dominic, I moved the implementations to teh header file and it worked. I never saw this aspect mentioned in any tutorial I read. So, why does the compiler need to see the implementation the same time it sees the code that calls them, i.e. what makes the templated fucntions unique in this regard?

Comment: The compiler needs to have the entire template definition available when it instantiates it - so that it can substitute the template parameters and evaluate it.
If your compiler supports it, you can declare your template as "extern" and use it the way you would any other member, at the cost of additional link-time work. GCC supports this as an extension. It's going to be part of the C++0x standard.

Comment: There are techniques to keep templates away, namely, forward declaring template specializations. -1 for "should never"

Comment: You answered in 2009 and helped me after 9 years, thank you :)

Comment: Why's '.cpp' wrong when using explicit instantiation?

Comment: I think what I meant (13 years ago!) is that explicit instantiation can complement implicit instantiation, so keep the definition in the header file so it can be instantiated on other types later. Of course, if you're 100% sure (which is the case sometimes, e.g. templating on enums) that those are the only types that will ever be needed, `.cpp` is the right choice.

Answer (score 10):

If you move the implementation of the templated methods (convert and readParameter) to the header file, it should work.

The compiler must have access to the implementations of templated functions at the points where they're instantiated.

Answer (score 6):

A template method is merely a ... template for a method.  The template arguments are to be filled in where the method is "instantiated".

It should be possible to build a compiler that is content with the declaration of a template method, and have a 'template compilation' step compile all the needed instances of the template method.

This is not the case for microsoft's vc.  I heard a collegue mutter about it being the case on unix, though.

Most compilers instantiate the template method on request, where they are used in the source code.  In order to instantiate the method, the compiler must 'see' the template function body.   That's why the body is most often placed in either the header file, or in e.g. a .h.cpp file, which is then included as the last line of the .h file.

Comment: What you're describing is an "extern template." It's included in the next version of the C++ standard and has been supported by GCC for a long time (as an extension). Visual C++ should support it in the current beta of the next release.

Comment: .h.cpp or .hpp?