# Boost .ini file parser - multiple section name(s)

Tags: c++, ini, boost-propertytree

I am using boost::property_tree to parse ini files.

I want to be able to do something like the following:

data.ini:

```
[electron]
position=0,0,0
velocity=0,0,0

[proton]
position=1,0,0
velocity=0,0,0

[proton]
position=-1,0,0
velocity=0,0,0
```

Currently the program runs, and gives this error: `duplicate section name` Obviously because there are two `[proton]` sections.

Is there an alternative way to parse a file like this? Should I perhaps be using an xml file?

Comment: Right, duplicate sections for INI files are not allowed.
But XML and JSON should be fine.

Comment: Okay thanks, just got to get to grips with xml parsing then.

Comment: Related question: [Boost property_tree: working with simple arrays or containers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4986052/1084416).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple reader, in case you need it:

**XML-file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <electron>
    <position>0,0,0</position>
    <velocity>0,0,0</velocity>
  </electron>
  <proton>
    <position>1,0,0</position>
    <velocity>0,0,0</velocity>
  </proton>
  <proton>
    <position>-1,0,0</position>
    <velocity>0,0,0</velocity>
  </proton>
</data>
```

**JSON-file:**

```
{
    "electron": {
        "position": "0,0,0",
        "velocity": "0,0,0"
    },
    "proton": {
        "position": "1,0,0",
        "velocity": "0,0,0"
    },
    "proton": {
        "position": "-1,0,0",
        "velocity": "0,0,0"
    }
}
```

Read XML & JSON proton nodes:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // XML
    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_xml("prop_data.xml", pt);

        for(auto& el : pt.get_child("data.proton"))
        {
            std::cout << el.second.data() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // JSON
    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_json("prop_data.json", pt);

        for(auto& el : pt.get_child("proton"))
        {
            std::cout << el.second.data() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
It is possible to use arrays for JSON, e.g:

```
...
"position": [-1, 0, 0],
...
```

And the code to read values of this array:

```
    for(auto& el : pt.get_child("proton"))
    {
        std::cout << el.first << std::endl;
        for(auto& a : el.second) {
            std::cout << a.second.data() << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Here `el.second` is just a ptree, and you can iterate through it using a for loop.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks that seems like the ticket. Can I use this with tags in this format: `<position="0,1,0">`

Comment: Btw, you can use arrays in JSON, something like: "position": [-1, 0, 0]

Comment: this is not an answer, since it answers for json and xml, but not for ini